# Kendo UI asp.net MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I have Kendo Grid  contains Row every Row have Edit button
if I press Edit and not change amount Loading and not call Function

```
.Update(aUpdate => aUpdate.Action("CreateUpdateArrearAmortizationInstallment", "LoanArrearAgreements", new { arrearID = arrearAccountID }).Data("getCreateUpdateInstallmentData"))
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you give more context on how youve set this up. 

Can you show the code in your each of the Model, Contoller and the View.  What is your desired and actual result.  What are your error messages and which part of the application do they come from?